# Ошибка в работе PageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Есть массив городов var cities = ["Minsk", "Moscow", "Astana"] и PageViewController, который для каждого города показывает погоду. PageViewController открывает контроллер с данными по индексу и передает контроллеру с данными инфу, которую нужно показать, которая во ViewDidLoad присваивается тексту лейблов. 
Происходит такая ошибка: при перелистывании страниц с данными третья по счету всегда показывает те же данные, что и вторая. Пробовал распечатать данные на каждом шаге и в дебагере верная инфа, а в приложении -нет. Проблема всегда на третьей странице, работает корректно только если города 2. Уже все перепробовано, может подскажете, куда копать... Ниже код.

```
class PageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

var cities = ["Minsk", "Moscow", "Astana"]

 func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    if index == 0 {
        return nil
    } else{
    index = index! - 1
    return openVC(for: index!)
}
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    if index == cities.count - 1 {
        return nil
    } else {
    index = index! + 1
    return openVC(for: self.index!)
}
}

func openVC(for index: Int) -> UIViewController? {
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "cityVC") as! CityViewController
    city = cities[self.index!]
        var currentCityData: CityWeatherData?
        for cityWeatherData in allCitiesWeatherData {
            if cityWeatherData.name == city {
                currentCityData = cityWeatherData
            }
        }
    vc.currentCityData = currentCityData
    self.pageControl.currentPage = self.index!
    return vc
    }
```

---

```
class CityViewController: UIViewController {

var currentCityData: CityWeatherData?

@IBOutlet weak var cityLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var temperatureLabel: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
                cityLabel.text = currentCityData?.name
                descriptionLabel.text = currentCityData?.description
                temperatureLabel.text = currentCityData?.temperature
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Дело в индексе. Индексация массива в Swift всегда начинается с нуля, а Вы хотите получить погоду по индексу, которого не существует

Comment: можете указать точнее, где именно это происходит?

Comment: Для этого укажите, что именно Вы имеете ввиду под этим: индексацию или сам индекс

Comment: Если Вы имеете ввиду выход индекса за пределы массива, то это у Вас происходит в ViewControllerBefore и ViewControllerAfter. В ViewControllerBefore в условии if, в ViewControllerAfter в обоих условиях

Comment: Т.е. индекс выходит за пределы массива там, где в условии сказано, что если index == cities.count - 1, то возращается nil. Индекс массива в Swift всегда меньше count. И индексация начинается с нуля